# callkit with pushkit in xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, callkit, pushkit

I'm trying to integrate callkit with pushkit in one of my app in xamarin using Twilio voip. I was able to do so by defining required classes and delegates.

I can receive a call when my app is in foreground. but when my app is backgrounded or killed, its not received.

I have this method in my appdelegate:

```
  [Export("pushRegistry:didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:forType:withCompletionHandler:")]
[Preserve(Conditional = true)]
public void DidReceiveIncomingPush(PKPushRegistry registry, PKPushPayload payload, string type, Action completion)
{
    try
    {
         Console.WriteLine("My push is coming (Inside Action method!");
        var callerid = payload.DictionaryPayload["twi_from"].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine($"from: {callerid}");
    
        completion= delegate {
                    if (payload != null)
                    {
                            TwilioService.Setnotification(payload);
                    }
                    };
                    completion.Invoke();
// Tried using only this
// completion(); but it didn't work.
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
     Console.WriteLine(ex.message);
    }
    }
```

So question is how to bring  Native dialer when call is arriving and app is in background or killed. I don't understand how to use "Action" parameter of above method.

I see this error in my device logs:

```
Info (114) / callservicesd: Application <private> will not be launched because it failed to report an incoming call too many times (or repeatedly crashed.)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @SoftSan, I'm experiencing the same thing. did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @RyanMotal - Yes there was some issue with my code itself, so i put try..catch block on my main.cs and logs the error in a file that way i found the error and fixed that. Also i used that completion to invoke when my I receive callinvite from twilio